# Trying to implement piecewise function in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I am trying to implement a piecewise function into Simulink. I know what it is supposed to look like but I am unable to get it correct so far.

The function is:
500*((sin(10t))^2) for 0 <= t < (pi/10)
0 for (pi/10) <= t < 0.8

I need it to plot over two periods (so 0 to 1.6).

I am trying to use the MATLAB function block to do so and have tried to plot the first period with the code below in the block:

function y = fcn(t)

if t < (pi/10)
y = 500*((sin(10*t)).^2)
else
y = 0;
end

How could I get this piecewise function to display in the scope?